# URL resolution error using Gunicorn, Nginx, and Django

Tags: python, django, nginx, proxy, gunicorn

I have a strange error occuring only when using Gunicorn :

I have a setup Nginx + a django project with the following config :

```
location / {
  proxy_pass       http://127.0.0.1:8080;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header SCRIPT_NAME /;
}
```

When I use the django development server (1.7.5) using:

```
./manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Everything works fine.

But when I run

```
gunicorn -b :8080 --forwarded-allow-ips="*" --proxy-allow-from="*" app.wsgi
```

I only get 404 errors (django is receiving requests as I have the debug messages).

These errors are strange because the variable *urlpatterns* (https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.7.5/django/views/debug.py#L1102) is not set. I only obtain the *reason* variable (https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.7.5/django/views/debug.py#L1119) set to :

```
{u'path': u'x/'}
```

as I requested http://domain.something.com/x/

What bothers be the most is that the basic server that comes with django works fine... :(

Comment: Have you tried connecting directly to gunicorn server, bypassing nginx? What will happen then?

Comment: Bypassing nginx works. But I can only bypass nginx for development purposes..

Comment: Have you tried starting up gunicorn binding to 0.0.0.0:8080 ?

Comment: Try to remove `proxy_set_header SCRIPT_NAME /;` from nginx config and then reload nginx.

Comment: I cannot modify the SCRIPT_NAME at the moment. However, I found that because of that statement, the leading '/' is removed from every request. What I cannot figure out for the moment is : Should Nginx remove the '/' ? and should the django wsgi handler take care of a missing leading '/'...

Comment: It's not nginx that removes leading /, it's django. That's how SCRIPT_NAME works, django will strip SCRIPT_NAME from beginning of the url when resolving and add it back on front when reversing urls. That way you can have your django installation in any directory without touching anything in your project.

Comment: And for future reference, answer to your question should be posted in answer, not added in question. If one of answers works for you, just accept that answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing

```
   proxy_set_header SCRIPT_NAME /;
```

from nginx config will do the job. It is how django treats `SCRIPT_NAME` header: when present, django will cut that value from the front of URL when resolving it, and will add it back to the front of the url when reversing it. That way you can tell django that all urls should be relative to certain directory without touching anything in your project. `SCRIPT_NAME` should be set without trailing / so correct value for root directory of your domain is an empty string (or total absence of `SCRIPT_NAME`).